# Update multiple columns and rows sql table

Tags: php, sql, database

I was reading How to update multiple rows with a single query but i have a question i want to know if you can help me.

I want to update multiple columns and rows with a single query but i need them to update like this:

If column1 and column2 (in all rows) == column1 and column2 (in specific row1) then update value in column3 (in all rows). if not equal then value Whatever but if > or < then value Whatever.

Example  :
                                       Column 1  ----  Column2 ----- Column3

```
 Row1     2       3                  
 Row2     2       3  (then)  Value1
 Row3     2       2  (then)  Value2
 Row4     2       3  (then)  Value1
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're saying is that you want to update rows based on matching to the values in a specific row.  We can achieve this by doing a left outer join.  If the values match then the join succeeds, so 'row1Match' will not be null.  If the values don't match then 'row1Match' will be null.  We can then use this to drive the update.

If we assume that the table (which I've called MyTable) has an ID column, and that 'Row1' in your example has an ID of 1, then you want something like this:

```
UPDATE toUpdate
SET Column3 = (CASE WHEN row1Match IS NOT NULL THEN 'Value1' ELSE 'Value2' END)
FROM MyTable toUpdate
     LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable row1Match ON row1Match.Column1 = toUpdate.Column1 
                                          AND row1Match.Column2 = toUpdate.Column2
WHERE row1Match.ID = 1
```